# AngularJs Material+Bootstrap Only for layouting purpose

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-material

I am making a simple test application and my manager asked me to use both angular material as well as bootstrap now angular material do provide layout code but we are using the bootstraps traditional method of mobile design now we are having the same code twice in our application that will lead to long loading time of the application. Is there any way I can use angular material for its UI/UX capabilities only like ripples effect and all componenets without using flex layouting(because its not supported by many web browsers)
315kb due to both of these will load is there any way I could make it half or atleast nearest possible value

Comment: One of the finest ripple effect in angular, check http://nelsoncash.github.io/angular-ripple/ and https://github.com/nelsoncash/angular-ripple

Comment: I not only concerned about ripple I want to reduce my dependency size but thanks bro

Comment: If you're using bootstrap you can use bootstrap material design theme and avoid angular material http://tilwinjoy.github.io/angular-bootstrap-material/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular Material is just a set of directives and some styling, so you could remove any module / directive that isn't a dependency of other modules / directives.

You'd likely be fine to remove things like the Ripple effect:
https://github.com/angular/material/tree/master/src/core/services

Or any of the individual components:
https://github.com/angular/material/tree/master/src/components

But you'd have to do thorough testing to make sure you didn't break anything.

You could probably also remove the layout styling:
https://github.com/angular/material/tree/master/src/core/style

From Bootstrap, you could probably remove any unused components:
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/tree/master/js

And their associated styling:
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/tree/master/less

For Bootstrap, the easiest way would be to use the customization tool:
http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

But for Angular you'll likely have to run your own custom build...